# how to do upwork authentication process triggered by azure function?

Tags: node.js, upwork-api

how to do upwork authentication process triggered by azure function? currently its OAuth 1.0 process to get verifier, but how to achieve it without asking verifier each time.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to ask for a verifier every time, It's enough to authenticate a user once, receive an access token/secret pair, keep them in a safe place, and re-use to sign all next requests. It is mentioned here - 
https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015933448-API-Authentication-and-Security

> Note that OAuth Request token expires in 600 sec. Once the Access
>   token is created it never expires.

Simply put, you don't need to go throw the authorization before every request. It's enough to complete it once for a particular user.